# Laravel eloquent: updating a parent record and creating a new record in another table with one form

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have two tables namely `machines` and `calls`. The `machines` table has a list of machines and their details. Currently, to log a fault call about a machine, the administrator will enter the `machine_number` (to ensure the machine is registered under the company). This number is used to search the `machines` table in the database and the result will be displayed in a form.

My problem is that I want to have a situation whereby as the form is submitted, the details of the machine will be updated in the `machines` table (in case the detail is changed) while a new row is created on the `calls` table (in order to log the fault call).

Here is the search function:

```
Route::any('/search_results',function(){
    $query = Input::get ( 'query' );
    $machine= Machine::where('machine_id','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();
    return view('/addNewCall')->with('machine', $machine)->withQuery($query);
});
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="{{route('Call.store')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @if(count($machine) > 0)
        @foreach($machine as $machine)
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="machine_id">{{ __('Machine ID') }}</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="machine_id" id="machine_id" class="form-control" style="padding: 20px;" value="{{$machine->machine_id}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:20px">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="machine_custodian">{{ __('Machine Custodian Name') }}</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="machine_custodian" id="machine_custodian" class="form-control" style="padding: 20px;" value="{{$machine->machine_custodian}}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:20px">
                <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="call_logged_on">{{ __('Call logged on') }}</label><br>
                    <input type="datetime-local" name="call_logged_on" id="call_logged_on" class="form-control" style="padding: 20px;" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 form-group" style="margin-top:20px">
                <label for="fault_description">{{ __('Fault Description') }}</label><br>
                <textarea name="fault_description" id="fault_description" class="form-control" rows="7" cols="50"  required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="assigned_FE">{{ __('Field engineer in charge') }}</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="assigned_FE" id="assigned_FE" class="form-control" style="padding: 20px;" value="{{$machine->assigned_FE}}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px; border: 0; margin-top:25px">{{ __('Log 
        Call') }}</button>
    @else
        <h2 style="margin:30px; font-style:italic; font-weight:lighter" class="text-center">Sorry, there is no ATM with the terminal id of "<b>{{ $query }}</b>" in our database</h2>
    @endif
</form>
```

here is my CallsController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'machine_id' => 'required',
        'machine_custodian' => 'required',
        'call_logged_on' => 'required',
        'fault_description' => 'required',
        'assigned_FE' => 'required',
    ]);
        //store in the database
    $call = new Call;
    $call->machine_id = $request->input('machine_id');
    $call->machine_custodian = $request->input('machine_custodian');
    $call->call_logged_on = $request->input('call_logged_on');
    $call->fault_description = $request->input('fault_description');
    $call->assigned_FE = $request->input('assigned_FE');
    $call->save();

    return redirect('/pages/newCall')->with('success', 'call created check pending calls to view call');
}
```

Currently, the code creates a new row in the `calls` table. But I don't know how to enhance the code to update the machine's information in the `machines` table.

**Note: `machine_id` column is different from `id` column in the `machines` table**

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the **NOTE**, If you don't have the id of machine how you need to update it?

Comment: I mean the `machine_id` is not auto incremented in the database...the `id` is contained in the search result array

Comment: Doesn't matter if it contains the foreign key of the machine object, what must be auto incremented in the database is the `id` in machines table.

Comment: @Austin If `machine_id` is the foreign key for `machine` table, it will never be an auto increment in `calls` table anyway.

Comment: Which columns in the machines table do you want to update?

Comment: yes the `id` is auto incremented...the **NOTE** contained in the question is just to specify that they both exist in the `machines` table and that they dont hold the same values

Comment: @vivek_23, `machine_id` is not a froeign key

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, the `machine_custodian` and `assigned_FE'

Comment: @Austin Ok, then what is it? When you are making the form in your blade, it is the one of the primary keys in your `machine` table. Sure, the user could change it, but why would you want him to do that?

Comment: @vivek_23, `machine_id` is unique to each machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the return statement you can get your "Machine" Object by `id` and update the columns you want using `update()` method :

```
$machine = Machine::find($call->machine_id);
$machine->update(['machine_custodian'=>$call->machine_custodian, 'assigned_FE'=>$call->assigned_FE]);
```

Could be also :

```
$machine = Machine::find($call->machine_id);
$machine->machine_custodian = $call->machine_custodian;
$machine->assigned_FE = $call->assigned_FE;
$machine->save();
```

Comment: I get a `Creating default object from empty value` error on```$machine->machine_custodian = $call->machine_custodian;```

Comment: Are you adding this code just before the `return`? could you please add `dd($call)` just after `$call->save();``line and show us the output?

Comment: yes,..`dd($machine)` returns null but `dd($call)` returns the array to be saved...meaning the code works fine until `$call->save();`

Comment: `dd($call->machine_id)` output?

Comment: `dd($call->machine_id)` gives the `machine_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190757/discussion-between-austin-and-zakaria-acharki).